# GAE Open-ID Federated Authentication using Java Script End Point

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-openid

I want to use GAE Open-ID Federated Authentication using Java Script (without Java Servlet) End Point.

Is it supported via Java Script (without Java Servlet) End Point?
If yes how could I use Open-ID Federated Authentication with Java Script end point API call?

I had tried User in endpoint API

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "signMe.signGoogleId",
        httpMethod = "POST",
        scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" }
    )
    public SignIn signInOpenId(User user)throws
      OAuthRequestException, IOException
    {

      User is null always even after logging with Google\Yahoo User.
```

I had tried HttpServletRequest req in endpoint API.

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "SignMe.signOpenId",
        httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET,
        scopes = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" }
    )
    public SignIn signInOpenId(HttpServletRequest req)
    throws IOException
{

UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User newUser = userService.getCurrentUser();

        newUser is null always even after logging with Google\Yahoo User.
```

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Has anyone used cloud-endpoints with federated-login option?

Answer (score 0):

You could always dump the cloud endpoints way of doing it and go with general API authentication.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid#fa

As would be done for non Cloud Endpoints applications. The down side is you wouldn't get any client authorization abilities, so any client code hit your API.

Google Cloud Endpoints OAuth does not seem to support Open ID at this time.